# Save timestamps for REST in Offline App

Tags: rest, timestamp, offline

I am writing an app with offline capabilities, with a REST interface as my middleware.

It's about a timetracking system for employees. 
The employees should be able start the timetracking, while their phone is offline. When the phone turns online, it should sync the time of the start/stop.

I'm using simple REST requests, which will be cached and send afterwards.
This REST contains a timestamp of the start/stop time for the timetracking.

Now the question:

**How i can make sure, that the timestamp is not manipulated ?**

Because it's a native app, i cant protect the REST interface by Access-Control-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

simply encrypt the timestamp from client side. On your server side decrypt the timestamp if there is a decryption failure that means somebody has manipulated the payload.

Comment: What kind of encryption algorithm would you suggest ?

Comment: it depends on how much security you want . if its simple application /poc  say a non banking/financibg app then a simple lower bit encryption is ok AES or anyother symmetric algo should be ok . If it is something financial admin/personal use popular sha2 with high bit encryption .Although higher bit encryption have country level mandates.Another possibilty will be to use oauth2